# Is Shopify production and development webhook response same?

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to know how Shopify calculates the webhook response time.

If the webhook task is completed within 0.2-sec, After that, how does it take 0.99 sec?
And I want to know whether webhook takes the same response time on development and production?

Answer (score 0):

Webhook response time or sending Shopify at 200 OK status is the *first* thing you do once you receive the data, since they can assume your webhook endpoint is *broken* if they do not get a response within seconds. If you fail to fire off your 200 OK status they just resend the webhook data, ultimately deleting your webhook if you never do send a 200 OK status. Note you also have to send a 401 now if they send you a bogus webhook too.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback. Yes, that I understand. 
I want to know, Is Shopify production time webhook response speed faster than development time webhook response speed?

And also want to know "How does Shopify calculate the webhook response time?"

Comment: No one can answer that question. To me, it makes no sense. There is no such thing as webhook response speed. That metric does not exist.

Comment: Is payload size also responsible to delay webhook response?

Comment: Define delayed webhook response? Until you define your problem, no one can help you. If you mean to say: "My webhook payload I just got is large, it'll take me a long time to process it, compared to a smaller webhook payload", I suggest you re-read my answer. You are doing it wrong. Respond 200 OK first, then process the data.